# magento 1 observer for special price end date

Tags: magento-1.9, special-price

Is any observer fire after special price date is ended ? Or did you have any idea for check when special is ended ? or maybe should i change this code function

```
    public static function calculateSpecialPrice($finalPrice, $specialPrice, $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo,
        $store = null)
{
    if (!is_null($specialPrice) && $specialPrice != false) {
        if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval($store, $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo)) {
            $finalPrice     = min($finalPrice, $specialPrice);
        }
    }
    return $finalPrice;
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your catalog ?

Comment: more than 7000 @Pawan

Comment: why Observer only, You can do with custom script also.